# Unwanted square around my sprite in Three.js

Tags: javascript, typescript, three.js

I try to create a "starry ski" in Three.js. But my stars which supposed to be transparent .png have a colored space around there.

My sprite in png :

[image]

The render :

[image]

Zoom on star :

[image]

My code (`.ts` file) :

```
stars: any;
starGeo = new Three.Geometry();

// Generate random stars 
for (let index = 0; index < 8000; index++) {
  const star = new Three.Vector3(
    Math.random() * 600 - 300,
    Math.random() * 600 - 300,
    Math.random() * 600 - 300
  );
  this.starGeo.vertices.push(star);
}

// Load png
const starSpriteFl = require('../assets/sprites/star.png');
// Create texture
const sprite = new Three.TextureLoader().load(starSpriteFl);

let starMaterial = new Three.PointsMaterial({
  size: 0.7,
  map: sprite,
});

this.stars = new Three.Points(this.starGeo, starMaterial);
this.scene.add(this.stars);
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Did you try `transparent: true` ?

Comment: No and that's it !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described by @soju, the parameter `transparent` was missing on `PointsMaterial` :

```
let starMaterial = new Three.PointsMaterial({
  size: 0.7,
  transparent: true,
  map: sprite,
});
```